# Fill inner area of a character with drawContours

Tags: c++, opencv, contour

I have an input image:

[image: input image]

I use few functions to find contours in this image:

```cpp
cv::Mat srcImg = cv::imread("input.png");
cv::Mat grayImg{};
cv::cvtColor(srcImg, grayImg, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
cv::Mat threshImg;
cv::adaptiveThreshold(grayImg, threshImg, 255, cv::ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv::THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 2);
```

My picture after thresholding is as below:

[image: after thresholding]

Now I want to find contours:

```cpp
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> ptContours{};
cv::findContours(threshImg, ptContours, cv::RETR_EXTERNAL, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

And here is my question: how can I use `drawContours()` to fill the inner area of the character `A`?

I want to achieve something like this:

[image: expected result]

Comment: No, `cv::drawContours(threshImg, ptContours, -1, cv::Scalar::all(255), cv::FILLED);` doesn't solve it, because it also fills the black triangle in the middle of the character.

Comment: did you try fillPoly answer too? It would be great if you edited your response into the question (so that future readers would get the context too).

Comment: Yes, `cv::fillPoly(threshImg, ptContours, cv::Scalar::all(255));` also doesn't do the job. The black triangle in the middle becomes white.

Comment: That's not really surprising, `A` consists of two contours -- outer one around the whole letter, and inner one around the enclosed triangle. You only requested the external one, and are filling just that with white. You also need to fill the inner contour black as a second step. If it was a `B`, you'd have one outer and two inner contours.

Comment: don't fix the consequences, prevent the situation. fix the adaptive thresholding. use a larger radius/kernel size and (relative) thresholds that aren't such a close call.

Comment: You should fix the threshold, but just in case you need it elsewhere, try cv::RETR_CCOMP instead of cv::RETR_EXTERNAL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get the binary image via [Otsu Thresholding](https://learnopencv.com/otsu-thresholding-with-opencv/), you get a nice binary blob without any "filling problems":

```
// Read the input image:
std::string imageName = "D://opencvImages//UZUd5.png";
cv::Mat testImage =  cv::imread( imageName );

// Convert BGR to Gray:
cv::Mat grayImage;
cv::cvtColor( testImage, grayImage, cv::COLOR_RGB2GRAY );

// Get Binary via Otsu:
cv::Mat binaryImage;
cv::threshold( grayImage, binaryImage, 0, 255, cv::THRESH_OTSU );
```

This is the result:

[image]

If you don't want to use Otsu, and instead use your current approach, this is a possible way of filling the blob. It basically filters every contour by area and hierarchy. I look for the outmost and inmost contours, and perform some flood-fills accordingly - outside of the outer contour, to fill the *canvas* and inside the inner contour to fill the *hole*:

```
// Get Binary via Adaptive Thresh:
cv::Mat binaryImage;
cv::adaptiveThreshold( grayImage, binaryImage, 255, cv::ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv::THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 2 );

// Containers:
std::vector< std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
std::vector< cv::Vec4i > hierarchy;

// Create a new matrix where things will be drawn:
cv::Mat filledBlob = cv::Mat::ones( binaryImage.size(), CV_8UC3 );

// Find contours:
cv::findContours(binaryImage, contours, hierarchy, cv::RETR_CCOMP, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

// Filling colors:
cv::Scalar fillColor = cv::Scalar( 0,0,0 );
cv::Scalar canvasColor = cv::Scalar( 255,255,255 );

for( int i = 0; i < (int)contours.size(); i++ ){
    // Get Blob area:
    float blobArea = cv::contourArea( contours[i] );
    // Filter smaller blobs:
    int minArea = 3000;
    if ( blobArea > minArea) {

        // Get contour heirarchy:
        int contourHierarchy = hierarchy[i][3];

        // Process the child contour:
        if ( contourHierarchy != -1 ){

            // Draw "hole":
            cv::drawContours( filledBlob, contours, (int)i, fillColor, 1, cv::LINE_8, hierarchy, 0 );
            // Get bounding rectangle:
            cv::Rect bBox = cv::boundingRect(contours[i]);
            // Compute centroid:
            cv::Point centroid;
            centroid.x = bBox.x + 0.5*bBox.width;
            centroid.y = bBox.y + 0.5*bBox.height;
            // Flood-fill at centroid with canvas color:
            cv::floodFill( filledBlob, centroid, canvasColor, (cv::Rect*)0, cv::Scalar(), 0);

        }else{

             // Process the parent contour:
            if ( contourHierarchy == -1 ){
                // Draw outline:
                cv::drawContours( filledBlob, contours, (int)i, fillColor, 1, cv::LINE_8, hierarchy, 0 );
                // Flood-fill at canvas (outside of contour):
                cv::floodFill( filledBlob, cv::Point( 1, 1 ), canvasColor, (cv::Rect*)0, cv::Scalar(), 0);
            }
        }

        // Show image
        cv::imshow( "Filled Blob", filledBlob );
        cv::waitKey(0);
    }
}
```

Which yields this image:

[image]

If you want an inverted image, just subtract `255 - filledBlob`:

```
cv::subtract( 255, filledBlob, filledBlob );
```